# Duplicate a div with a Bootstrap button

Tags: javascript, html

I've been messing around with this for a couple of hours now, but for the life of me, cannot seem to get it to work, so any help greatly appreciated.

For context, I have a page which has a bootstrap form contained within it, the form contains divs which contain the form elements. There are 5 divs and the page by default, but I have a button, that when clicked I want to duplicate and continue to add as many additional "lines" to the form as the user would like.

This is the code I have in the button itself, within the bootstrap html doc:

```
<button style="margin-top:30px" id="button" onclick="duplicate()">ADD NEW LINE</button>
```

And this is the javascript that I have:

```
    document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;


var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');

function duplicate() {
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
    clone.id = "duplicater" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

The Javascript file is physically located (locally at present) at /js/addnewline.js

And I have it referenced at the bottom of the HTML page like this:

```
<script src="/js/addnewline.js"></script>
```

When loading up the page and clicking the button, nothing happens.

Any pointers are welcomed.

Thank you in advance,
Gavin

Answer (score 0):

you have a wrong id in you button. you have id="button" instead of id="duplicater"

this is your solution:

```
<button style="margin-top:30px" id="duplicater" onclick="duplicate()">ADD NEW LINE</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Luis. I have changed the line you refer to, however, still nothing happens "onclick"?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line "   document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;" here you have defined the click event but at the same time you have used onclick inside the button remove this "   document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;"  line and the id of the button should be duplicater

```
<button style="margin-top:30px" id="duplicater" onclick="duplicate()">ADD NEW LINE</button>




var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');
console.log(original)

function duplicate() {
 console.log(original)
var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
clone.id = "duplicater" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for the feedback. Unfortunately, it still doesnt do anything when clicking.  

The JS is now:

var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');

function duplicate() {
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
    clone.id = "duplicater" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}

And the button on the html page is now:

<button style="margin-top:30px" id="duplicater" onclick="duplicate()">ADD NEW LINE</button>